# Query operation in Mongodb to find first 10 row from find left outer between two query from the same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need help to find the first 10 document from left outer between two queries from the same collection fastly.

Let just say i one collection with the below records:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(1), 
    "clientId" : "1", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "clientId" : "2", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(3), 
    "clientId" : "3", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(4), 
    "clientId" : "4", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(5), 
    "clientId" : "5", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(6), 
    "clientId" : "6", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(7), 
    "clientId" : "7", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}

{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(8), 
    "clientId" : "6", 
    "requestId" : "200"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(9), 
    "clientId" : "7", 
    "requestId" : "200"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(10), 
    "clientId" : "8", 
    "requestId" : "200"
}
....
```

Here I have almost 3M records with requestId:100 and 2M records with requestId:200.
I need to find to first 10 records which client Ids have "mainRequestId" but not in "excludedRequestId".

My Query is :

```
let mainRequestId = "100";
let excludedRequestId = "200";

db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { requestId: mainRequestId } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "clientId",
      foreignField: "clientId",
      as: "results"
    }
  },
  { $match: { "results.requestId": {$ne: excludedRequestId} } },
  { $limit: 10},
])
```

I have also index requesId and clientId, and also a compound index for both the fields. But this query takes more than 2 minutes.

Is there better way to faster this operation.

Thanks.

Comment: The second match refers to a `results` field, but the data doesn't appear to have one?

Comment: I have edited question.

Comment: do you already have indexes on requestId and clientId?

Answer (score 0):

Put your `$match` in `$lookup` `pipeline`.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      requestId: "100"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "requestId": {
              $ne: "200"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      localField: "clientId",
      foreignField: "clientId",
      as: "results"
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F8UmnDRGjxW)

Comment: I have got error "$lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'".

Comment: check this [pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748716/lookup-with-pipeline-may-not-specify-localfield-or-foreignfield)

Comment: I have checked already, But none of them solve my problem.