# MongoDb query to exclude omission of rows based on criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In below example, looking for new partner suggestions for user abc. `abc` has already sent a request to `123` so that can be ignored. `rrr` has sent request to `abc` but `rrr` is in the `fromUser` field so `rrr` is still a valid row to be shown as suggestion to `abc`

I have two collections:

1. User collection

```
[
    {
      _id: "abc",
      name: "abc",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "xyz",
      name: "xyyy",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "123",
      name: "yyy",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "rrr",
      name: "tttt",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "eee",
      name: "uuu",
      group: 1
    }   
]
```

2. Partnership collection (if users have already partnered)

```
[
    {
      _id: "abc_123",
      fromUser: "abc",
      toUser: "123"
    },
    {
      _id: "rrr_abc",
      fromUser: "rrr",
      toUser: "abc"
    },
    {
      _id: "xyz_rrr",
      fromUser: "xyz",
      toUser: "rrr"
    }   
]
```

My query below excludes the user `rrr` but it should not because its not listed in `toUser` field in the partnership collection corresponding to the user `abc`.

How to modify this query to include user `rrr` in this case?

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      group: 1,
      _id: {
        $ne: "abc"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "partnership",
      let: {
        userId: "$_id"
      },
      as: "prob",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $set: {
            users: [
              "$fromUser",
              "$toUser"
            ],
            u: "$$userId"
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$userId",
                    "$users"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $in: [
                    "abc",
                    "$users"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "prob.0": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sample: {
      size: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "prob"
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/utGMeHFRGmt

Comment: it is listed on `fromUser` with `abc`. Should it be allowed to create the opposite connection?

Comment: Can you extend your question and clarify what the expected result is and what the rules are?

Comment: @Markus - Sure - In above example, we are looking for new partner suggestions for user abc. `abc` has already sent a request to `123` so that can be ignored. `rrr` has sent request to `abc` but `rrr` is in the `fromUser` field so `rrr` is still a valid row to be shown as suggestion to `abc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query does not allow creating an existing connection regardless of the connection direction. If the order of the connection is important use:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      group: 1,
      _id: {$ne: "abc"}
    }
  },
  {$lookup: {
      from: "partnership",
      let: { userId: {$concat: ["abc", "_", "$_id"]}},
      as: "prob",
      pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$_id", "$$userId"]}}}]
    }
  },
  {$match: {"prob.0": {$exists: false}}},
  {$sample: {size: 1}},
  {$unset: "prob"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5cjhvHent-i)

Comment: This works and is the expected result. I am however doubtful about using the _id `userId1_userId2` to find if partnership collection has a row where user1 and user2 are present. Can this same result be achieved using `fromUser` and `toUser`

Comment: Sure, in this case use [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BNndA1CfVnU)

Answer (score 2):

For MongoDB 5 and later, I'd propose the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      group: 1,
      _id: {
        $ne: "abc"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "partnership",
      as: "prob",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "toUser",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            fromUser: "abc",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "prob.0": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "prob"
  }
])
```

The following documents are returned (full result without the $sample stage):

```
[
  {
    "_id": "eee",
    "group": 1,
    "name": "uuu"
  },
  {
    "_id": "rrr",
    "group": 1,
    "name": "tttt"
  },
  {
    "_id": "xyz",
    "group": 1,
    "name": "xyyy"
  }
]
```

The main difference is that the lookup connects the collections by the `toUser` field (see `localField`, `foreignField`) and uses a minimal pipeline to restrict the results further to only retrieve the requests from the current user document to "abc".

See this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_qRBAub20Ss) to test.

---

When using MongoDB < 5, you cannot use `localField` and `foreignField` to run the pipeline only on a subset of the documents in the  * from*
collection. To overcome this, you can use this aggregation pipeline:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      group: 1,
      _id: {
        $ne: "abc"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "partnership",
      as: "prob",
      let: {
        userId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$fromUser",
                    "abc"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$toUser",
                    "$$userId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "prob.0": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "prob"
  }
])
```

The results are the same as for the upper pipeline.

See this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f5nUPx2Seg_) to test.

Comment: `$lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'` - I am still on 4.4.1 and looks like above is only available with version 5. Looks good so trying to tweak this to make it work with v4.4. Thanks

Comment: Why does it not work on 4.4? It only changes the $lookup in comparison to your query and that should be supported on 4.4. Btw: I've removed the `let` and added a new link to the playground

Comment: Still getting error - `$lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748716/lookup-with-pipeline-may-not-specify-localfield-or-foreignfield

Comment: `localField` and `foreignField` can only be used with `pipeline` from MongoDB 5. I've missed this. In the answer, you can find a sample on how to overcome this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

For another, another way, this query starts from the `partnership` collection, finds which users to exclude, and then does a `"$lookup"` for everybody else. The remainder is just output formatting, although it looks like you may want to add a `"$sample"` stage at the end.

```js
db.partnership.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "fromUser": "abc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "exclude": {"$push": "$toUser" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "let": {
        "exclude": {"$concatArrays": [["abc"], "$exclude"]
        }
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$not": {"$in": ["$_id", "$$exclude"]}
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "output"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "output": 1
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$output"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$output"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-XbE-x14xX8).